# Launch Spring Batch Job from Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I need to download a file from remote SFTP server and process them using spring batch. I already implemented code using Spring Integration to download files. But I can't launch Spring Batch job from spring integration components. I have following code:

```
    @Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

public String OUTPUT_DIR = "temp_dir";

@Value("${sftp.remote.host}")
private String sftpRemoteHost;

@Value("${sftp.remote.user}")
private String sftpUsername;

@Value("${sftp.remote.password}")
private String sftpPassword;

@Value("${sftp.remote.folder}")
private String sftpFolder;

@Bean
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(sftpRemoteHost);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setUser(sftpUsername);
    factory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    final SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpFolder);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    final SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(OUTPUT_DIR));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    final FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(OUTPUT_DIR));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
    handler.setExpectReply(true);
    handler.setOutputChannelName("parse-csv-channel");
    return handler;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "parse-csv-channel", outputChannel = "job-channel")
public JobLaunchRequest adapt(final File file) throws Exception {
    final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString(
            "input.file", file.getAbsolutePath()).toJobParameters();
    return new JobLaunchRequest(batchConfiguration.job(), jobParameters);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "job-channel", outputChannel = "finish")
public JobLaunchingMessageHandler jobHandler(JobLaunchRequest request) throws JobExecutionException {
    return new JobLaunchingMessageHandler(jobLauncher);//.launch(request);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "finish")
public void finish() {
    System.out.println("FINISH");
}
```

But this does not work (error in last method `adapt`), because not bean of type File found. I can't clue this two parts together. How to wire integration and batch processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely just have to remove the `@Bean` annotation from your `adapt()` method. We need `@Bean`  if we really build `MessageHandler` bean, for example `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` to accept that `JobLaunchRequest` payload: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages.

See more info about Messaging Annotations in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans

**UPDATE**

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    final FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(OUTPUT_DIR));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
    handler.setExpectReply(true);
    handler.setOutputChannelName("parse-csv-channel");
    return handler;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "parse-csv-channel", outputChannel = "job-channel")
public JobLaunchRequest adapt(final File file) throws Exception {
    final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString(
            "input.file", file.getAbsolutePath()).toJobParameters();
    return new JobLaunchRequest(batchConfiguration.job(), jobParameters);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "job-channel")
public JobLaunchingGateway jobHandler() {
    JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher);
    jobLaunchingGateway.setOutputChannelName("finish");
    return jobLaunchingGateway;
}
```

Comment: and how to combine both `JobLaunchingMessageHandler ` and my `FileWritingMessageHandler`?

Comment: Not sure in your concern. You should remove `@Bean` from the `adapt()` method and add `outputChannel` to its `@ServiceActivator` to send the result to the `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` endpoint definition. And one should be similar to what you have with the `FileWritingMessageHandler`

Comment: I updated the original question - added new code. I tried to add more configuration as you mentioned, but it does not work. I made debug points in last 2 methods and this code never called. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `FileWritingMessageHandler` must be with the `setExpectReply(true)` - the default value though. And the file will really be sent to the `parse-csv-channel` for `JobLaunchRequest` transformation. Your `launch()` method is redundant. You have there `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` on the matter. That's all

Comment: don't know whats wrong. I updated code again. The batch job doesn't launch but file downloading works every 5 seconds. And after each downloading job doesn't run. This makes me crazy

Comment: `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` must be `@Bean` and its bean method should not have any parameters.

Comment: `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` is not reqeust-reply `MessageHandler`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchingMessageHandler.java. It doesn't implement `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`. So, your `outputChannel = "finish"` won't have effect as well. Please, read Spring Integration Reference Manual carefully. You should distinguish `@ServiceActivator` definition on the POJO method and on the `@Bean` method for the `MessageHandler` implementation

Comment: I see a lot of XML configuration in official docs. Is it possible to avoid XML configuration and use only annotation config? for example, here https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample configuration is mixed - I see `FileMessageToJobRequest` it's annotated as `@Transformer` and again in xml marked as transformed. It's confusing

Comment: Sure! That's really possible. That's why I show you that link to figure out how to use `@Bean` together with the Messaging Annotations.

Comment: Do you have examples without XML configuration? https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample here is mixed annotation and xml configuration. I can't understand why it's so sophisticated

Comment: Sorry, I don't but see my answer.

Comment: You use `@Bean` together with the `@ServiceActivator` only if you use `MessageHandler` implementation. If you have arbitrary POJO service method, the `@ServiceActivator` is enough. But your POJO must be as a bean (`@Service`) anyway.

Comment: if I remove `outputChannel` in the annotation for `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` it fails with `DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available`. But as I understood I should not put any outputChannels. how it's possible?

Comment: Doh.. Sorry. See edit code in my answer. You have to use `JobLaunchingGateway` isntead. The `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` isn't `MessageHandler` at all